# How to create a scale dependent function that increases the size of the symbol marker using ArcGIS JS 4.11?X

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, gis, arcgis-js-api

I have a variable called scale_condition

```
var scale_condition= 0;
```

Here i have the variable for the marker symbol. The size references the first variable scale_condition

```
var Facilities_Symbol = {
        type: "simple", // autocasts as new SimpleRenderer()
        symbol: {
          type: "simple-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
          size: scale_condition,
          color: "black",
          style: "circle"

        },
  };
```

Here i have a conditional statement that acknowledges the change in scale. However I also want it to assign a new scale_condition value whenever the scale parameters are met.

```
view.watch('scale', function(newScale) {
        console.log("Scale: ", newScale);
        if (newScale > 500000) {
            scale_condition=5;
       } else {
            scale_condition=70;
        }
    });
```

My issue is that though the code acknowledges the changes of the scale it does not assign a new scale_condition value to the Facilities_Symbol variable. It's like scale_condition from the function is not linked to the scale_condition variable. I feel I am close to the solution, but need some tweaks to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, my solution was to define two different renderers and replace the graphicLayer's symbol renderer in the scale watch function.
My solution is based on a graphicLayer, not sure how you add the graphic to the map.

```
var S_Symbol = {
     type: "simple-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
     size: 5,
     color: "black",
     style: "circle"
};
var L_Symbol = Object.assign({}, S_Symbol);
L_Symbol.size = 70;
var S_Renderer = {
    type: "simple", // autocasts as new SimpleRenderer()
    symbol: S_Symbol 
};
var L_Renderer = {
    type: "simple", // autocasts as new SimpleRenderer()
    symbol: L_Symbol 
};
view.watch('scale', function(newScale) {
    console.log("Scale: ", newScale);
    //Change the layer renderer 
    graphicsLayer.renderer = newScale > 500000 ?
                    S_Renderer: L_Renderer;
});
```